# gsub speed vs pattern length

Tags: regex, r, string, gsub, stringi

I've been using `gsub` extensively lately, and I noticed that short patterns run faster than long ones, which is not surprising. Here's a fully reproducible code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(12345)
n = 0
rpt = seq(20, 1461, 20)
msecFF = numeric(length(rpt))
msecFT = numeric(length(rpt))
inp = rep("aaaaaaaaaa",15000)

for (i in rpt) {
  n = n + 1
  print(n)
  patt = paste(rep("a", rpt[n]), collapse = "")
  #time = microbenchmark(func(count[1:10000,12], patt, "b"), times = 10)
  timeFF = microbenchmark(gsub(patt, "b", inp, fixed=F), times = 10)
  msecFF[n] = mean(timeFF$time)/1000000.

  timeFT = microbenchmark(gsub(patt, "b", inp, fixed=T), times = 10)
  msecFT[n] = mean(timeFT$time)/1000000.
}

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

axis(1,at=seq(0,1000,200),labels=T)

p1 = qplot(rpt, msecFT, xlab="pattern length, characters", ylab="time, msec",main="fixed = TRUE" )
p2 = qplot(rpt, msecFF, xlab="pattern length, characters", ylab="time, msec",main="fixed = FALSE")
grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 2)
```

As you see, I'm looking for a pattern that contains `a` replicated `rpt[n]` times. The slope is positive, as expected. However, I noticed a kink at 300 characters with `fixed=T` and 600 characters with `fixed=F` and then the slope seems to be approximately as before (see plot below). 
I suppose, it is due to memory, object size, etc. I also noticed that the longest allowed `pattern` is 1463 symbols, with object size of 1552 bytes.

**Can someone explain the kink better and why at 300 and 600 characters?**

[image: gsub speed in milliseconds with fixed turned on/off as a function of pattern length in characters]

Added: it is worth mentioning, that most of my patterns are 5-10 characters long, which gives me on my real data (not the mock-up `inp` in the example above) the following timing.

```
gsub, fixed = TRUE: ~50 msec per one pattern
gsub, fixed = FALSE: ~190 msec per one pattern
stringi, fixed = FALSE: ~55 msec per one pattern
gsub, fixed = FALSE, perl = TRUE: ~95 msec per one pattern
```

(I have 4k patterns, so total timing of my module is roughly 200 sec, which is exactly 0.05 x 4000 with gsub and fixed = TRUE. It is the fastest method for my data and patterns)

[image: Real data timing]

Comment: Not at all an answer to your question, still it was interesting to see that a `stringi` equivalent `stringiF <- microbenchmark(stri_replace_all_fixed(str = inp, pattern = patt, replacement = "b"), times = 10)`; `mean_stringiF[n] <- mean(stringiF$time)/1000000`; `qplot(rpt, mean_stringiF)`, showed no similar increase with pattern length, at least not over the range tested here.

Comment: If I use `perl=TRUE` in `gsub` with `fixed=FALSE` I also see no slope (doesn't matter for `fixed = TRUE`). However, I do need to use `fixed = TRUE` as it is substantially faster in my application

Comment: I know why in `stri_replace` function execution time jumps at 5 :) Because for patterns longer or equal to 5, the KMP algorithm is used. For patterns shorter than 5 plain naive search is done.

Comment: Your plots would be cleaner if your domain started at n=2 instead of n=1.  By cleaner I mean that the region of interest would own the majority of the space on the graph.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Can someone explain the kink better and why at 300 and 600 characters?

Answer (score 4):

The kinks might be related to the bits required to hold patterns of that length.

There is another solution that scales much better, use the repetition operator `{}` to specify how many repeats you want to find. In order to find more than 255 (8 bit integer max) you'll have to specify `perl = TRUE`.

```
patt2 <- paste0('a{',rpt[n],'}')
timeRF <- microbenchmark(gsub(patt2, "b", inp, perl = T), times = 10)
```

I get speeds of around 2.1 ms per search with no penalty for pattern length. That's about 8x faster than fixed = FALSE for small pattern lengths and about 60x faster for large pattern lengths.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, all my patterns are unique and typically just regular words with no repeats. For my application the fixed=FALSE provides the most correct (though slower than fixed=TRUE) solution due to other characters that might accompany the target (e.g. "caps," etc)

Comment: Here's a live example. `a = "appless, appless. apples-` . I need to changes `apples' to 'apple', leaving all punctuation intact. I have another thread on it, why and what I need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367914/r-how-to-prevent-memory-overflow-when-using-mgsub-in-vector-mode/27384067#27384067