# R: gsub with fixed=T or F and special cases

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Building on top of two questions I previously asked:

[R: How to prevent memory overflow when using mgsub in vector mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367914/r-how-to-prevent-memory-overflow-when-using-mgsub-in-vector-mode/27390847?noredirect=1#comment45052223_27390847)

[gsub speed vs pattern length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534296/gsub-speed-vs-pattern-length)

I do like suggestions on usage of fixed=TRUE by @Tyler as it speeds up calculations significantly. However, it's not always applicable. I need to substitute, say, `caps` as a stand-alone word w/ or w/o punctuation that surrounds it. A priori it's not know what can follow or precede the word, but it must be any of regular punctuation signs (, . ! - + etc). It cannot be a number or a letter. Example below. `capsule` must stay as is.

```
i = "Here is the capsule, caps key, and two caps, or two caps. or even three caps-"          

orig = "caps"
change = "cap"

gsub_FixedTrue <- function(i) {
  i = paste0(" ", i, " ")
  orig = paste0(" ", orig, " ")
  change = paste0(" ", change, " ")

  i = gsub(orig,change,i,fixed=TRUE)
  i = gsub("^\\s|\\s$", "", i, perl=TRUE)

  return(i)
}

#Second fastest, doesn't clog memory
gsub_FixedFalse <- function(i) {

  i = gsub(paste0("\\b",orig,"\\b"),change,i)

  return(i)
}

print(gsub_FixedTrue(i)) #wrong
print(gsub_FixedFalse(i)) #correct
```

Results. Second output is desired

```
[1] "Here is the capsule, cap key, and two caps, or two caps. or even three caps-"
[1] "Here is the capsule, cap key, and two cap, or two cap. or even three cap-"
```

Comment: Do what precisely is the question? You want to be able to use `fixed=TRUE` with a pattern that's not fixed? It doesn't work like that. Or you're trying to create a fixed expression equivalent to a non-fixed expression? The whole point of regular expressions is that matching like that is tedious with fixed strings.

Comment: Well, I was hoping that there might be a way to quickly strip the comma or full stop, do `gsub` with `fixed=TRUE` and stitch comma back to changed word. I have a solution for all other cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parts from your previous question to test I think we can put a place holder in front of punctuation as follows, without slowing it down too much:

```
line <- c("one", "two one", "four phones", "and a capsule", "But here's a caps key",
    "Here is the capsule, caps key, and two caps, or two caps. or even three caps-" )
e <- c("one", "two", "caps")
r <- c("ONE", "TWO", "cap")


line <- rep(line, 1700000/length(line))

line <- gsub("([[:punct:]])", " <DEL>\\1<DEL> ", line, perl=TRUE)

## Start    
line2 <- paste0(" ", line, " ")
e2 <-  paste0(" ", e, " ")
r2 <- paste0(" ", r, " ")


for (i in seq_along(e2)) {
    line2 <- gsub(e2[i], r2[i], line2, fixed=TRUE)
}

gsub("^\\s|\\s$| <DEL>|<DEL> ", "", line2, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out on real data that I am working with and have known results with 'fixed = FALSE'.

Comment: Tyler, you are genius!! This works! Thank you very much. May I add just a suggestion to do `  i <- gsub("([[:punct:]])", " <DEL>\\1<DEL> ", i, perl=TRUE)` and `  i = gsub("^\\s|\\s$| <DEL>|<DEL> ", "", i, perl=TRUE)
` to treat situations like `-caps,`

Comment: Makes sense, you can add as an edit (if you have the points to do so; if not I'll add it).  Glad it was helpful.

Comment: I probably don't have enough points - tried but didn't work. Thank you again! That <DEL> trick was great!